# Hibernate Query for unmapped join table

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I'm a J2EE newbie trying to learn Hibernate.   I have two tables, System and Game, and a join table called Systems_game.

I want to be able to put in an game_id and get all of the systems for that game.

I am using Annotations on the System.java and Game.java to create the many-to-many relationship.

```
@ManyToMany(targetEntity = System.class, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinTable(name="Systems_game",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name="game_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name="system_id") })
private List<Game> games;
```

And here is the method I am using to try to get the result I want.

```
@Override
public List getGameSystem(){
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Systems_game S WHERE S.game_id=1").list();              
}
```

When this runs, I get
"Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Systems_game is not mapped [from Systems_game S WHERE S.game_id=1]"

I know that I don't have systems_game mapped in my hibernate.cfg.xml file, but I don't know how to map this since I don't have a class for it.  Do I need to do my many-to-many relationship a different way and give it it's own class?   Any other way that I am overlooking that will help me achieve the desired result?

If you need more code then I will post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 ways to do this:

1. sql way:

   sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createNativeQuery("select * from systems_game s where s.game_id=1")...
2. hibernate(java) way:

   game = session.createQuery(from game where id = 1).uniqueResult()
   List systems = game.getSystems()

just try the pseudocode！

Answer (score 0):

HQL is about objects and you shouldn't stick to your database schema.

```
from SYSTEM as s join s.games as g where g.id=:id
```

This is what you need.